# Margin difference Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, margin

Using [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin the following [**example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obwvRg) was created, and the issue I am currently stuck with is that margin right that I set up for `div` with images in text doesn't look same in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. I've tried and add [normilize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), but the issue is still there.

I've presented the code for 940px and 1366px resolutions, there is also min 1px resolution so you can hide the general code for easier look. In chrome there are 2 columns for 940 and 3 columns for 1366.

**CSS with margin-right on line 323 for 940 res**

```
.composition-place {
      width: 30.24%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 4.55%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      float: left;
    }
```

**CSS with margin-right on line 382 for 1366 res**

```
.composition-place {
      width: 22.845%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: 2.9%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      float: left;
    }
```

Can you please suggest how the following issue can be figured out?

Comment: Wherever your js is setting the `top` and `left` values for your absolutely positioned divs is where the issue is occurring. It has nothing to do with your css.

Comment: @That doesn't explain the differences in margins in the OP's codepen. Given the same width (resized to half the desktop each), the right margin for the composition-place divs becomes 28px on Chrome, 42px on Mozilla.

Comment: @mrlister do you have any suggestions what that can be?

Comment: @Andrew Not yet. Still checking. Stand by!

Comment: @MrLister thank you a lot!